# Time-varying values in Rx

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, system.reactive

I have two observables. One is from `Observable.fromEvent(..)`, where the underlying event is the user checking a Winforms checkbox. The other is `Observable.Interval(..)` which I subscribe to in order to do some IO, and I would like to prevent this observable from doing IO, whenever the checkbox is not checked.

I could do it like this:

```
var gui = new GUI();

var booleans = Observable
    .FromEvent<GUI.NewAllowHandler, bool>(
        h => gui.NewAllow += h,
        h => gui.NewAllow -= h)

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
          .CombineLatest(booleans, Tuple.Create)
          .Where(t => t.Item2)
          .Select(t => t.Item1)
          .Subscribe(l => DoStuff(l));
```

but this has the overhead of mixing the booleans in and out of the stream. A nicer way of doing this would be, if I could generate a time-varying value from the `booleans` variable, which at all times had the value of the last event. Then I could do something like this:

```
var gui = new GUI();

var booleanState = Observable              // typeof(booleanState) == ???
    .FromEvent<GUI.NewAllowHandler, bool>(
        h => gui.NewAllow += h,
        h => gui.NewAllow -= h)
    .TimeValue()                           // hypothetical syntax


Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
          .Where(_ => booleanState) 
          .Subscribe(l => DoStuff(l));
```

, which to me seems much closer to the problem statement. Is there anything like this in Rx, or is there anything else, that could make such problems easier to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to model the checkbox checked state as Behavior and not as Event stream (because behavior has always a value and this value changes over a period of time - which fits with checkbox checked state). So you can do something like:

```
var booleans = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(chk.Checked)
var chkEvents = ... //generate boolean observable from checkbox check event
chkEvents.Subscribe(booleans);

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
 .Where(i => booleans.First())
 .Subscribe(i => DoIO());
```

Comment: Thanks, a Behaviour was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Boris - this solution means that you start with an object that has state (`chk.Checked`), turn it into an observable, and then subscribe to that observable to create an object that has state (`BehaviorSubject`) and then use that in the `Where` clause. Why create the middleman? Just go with `.Where(i => chk.Checked)` - it's simpler.

Comment: @Enigmativity - The middle man (the behavior) is the abstraction here for the interval based task which needs to know when to stop and when to start. Using checkbox in the interval task directly will create a strong dependency

Comment: @Ankur - a `BehaviourSubject` isn't an abstraction - it's replacing one dependency with another - and it's more fragile. If it used a pure `IObservable` query then I'd agree it was an abstraction.

Comment: @Enigmativity - BehaviorSubject does implement IObservable (and IObserver) as well, so you can pass it wherever a IObservable is required. My point was that in case you want to simulate the interval task with some Unit test then using a Behavior would be easy then a UI control.

Comment: @Ankur - I understand that subjects are observables. My point was that `BehaviourSubject` is as much of a dependency as the check box. I suggested using a "pure" observable to differentiate queries (against the source data) from subjects. If you want an abstraction in this situation then I'd look at using `Func<T, bool>` - in actual fact that's what you've got with `i => booleans.First()`. It just looks like it's using an observable - it's really a `Func<long, bool>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity - `Func<long,bool>` will act as another layer of abstraction. The main idea to suggest Behavior was that in Reactive programming you have these 2 types behaviors and Event and in this particular case the Checkbox is more close to behavior then event.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I appreciate your desire to simplify. There are three reasons that I like the Behaviour approach. First, I need the boolean event stream for other things, so it is not much more work to turn it into a behaviour. Second, this may not be a problem here, since bools are so small, but in general, doesn't this approach solve a potential race condition, where you risk reading half-new/half-old values from a property? And third, I like it that I can cast my problem explicitly in terms of events and behaviours, since it fits with some material I read about reactive programming (cont'ed)

Comment: (cont'ed) in Haskell. None of these three reasons by themselves are compelling, and my evaluation of them may change over time, but at the moment, for me, their combination wins over the simplicity offered by your approach.

Comment: @Boris - I'm curious to know what you mean by bools being small? Also, what race condition are you referring to?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I mean that bools are encoded in 4 bytes or less. If the value needed more bytes, then on a 32 bit machine I think reading the value would be a composite operation, reading the first 4 bytes, then the rest. If the reader was interrupted while reading, then the value, when finally read completely, could be composed of some bytes from the old value, and some bytes from the new. My guess is that somewhere in the implementation of BehaviourSubject, somebody has thought of that and put in place the appropriate locks, but I am not certain. I need to test this on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: @Boris - The standard Rx operators don't allow these kinds of race conditions. No `OnNext` operation begins before the previous one completes. You do not need to worry about any of these issues. It's actually a reason to use a pure Rx solution rather than one that isn't.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Ok, so this means that using `BehaviourSubject` avoids that race condition, right? Reading the cached value of `BehaviourSubject.First` will not be interrupted by another thread updating that value? I ask, since I am not sure exactly what your answer implies, but to me it seems to imply that my previous assertion was correct: Using `BehaviourSubject` will avoid a potential race condition (since it is a part of Rx) stemming from reading directly from a property.

Comment: @Boris - `BehaviourSubject` is safe - there's a lock around updating the value in its `OnNext` method and the same lock on sending the latest value to a new subscriber. But, if you use any of the schedulers then it is easy to create a race condition on a call to `.First()` on a subject. Erik Meijer, on of the creators of Rx said that if you're using a subject you're doing something wrong. It's best to use the standard Rx operators rather than the subjects to avoid dead-locks.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Ok, that was also the implementation I would have guessed at. I have some questions in relation to your last comment, but I will post those as regular questions. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The `Where` statement in your interval should work with a properly scoped normal bool:

```
var booleans = Observable
    .FromEvent<GUI.NewAllowHandler, bool>(
        h => gui.NewAllow += h,
        h => gui.NewAllow -= h)

var isBoxChecked = false;
booleans.Subscribe(t => isBoxChecked = t);

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    .Where(_ => isBoxChecked)
    .Subscribe(l => DoStuff(l))
```

Edit: Per your comment, another way of doing it:

```
intervals = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

booleans
    .Where(t => t)
    .SelectMany(_ => intervals.TakeUntil(booleans))
    .Subscribe(l => DoStuff(l))
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. This is another way of achieving my goal, and it is closer to my ideal syntax, but I think this is a little bit dangerous to accept. For instance, what if the event variable was not a bool, but another value whose size was more than 4 bytes, and the code was executed on a 32 bit machine? Wouldn't there be a race condition, with the risk of reading a half-updated value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you two solutions. The first is a very simple and hopefully obvious one using only one observable. The second is a uses both observables.

Since you want to allow the IO only when the box is checked then this is the simplest approach:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    .Where(_ => gui.IsChecked)
    .Subscribe(l => DoStuff(l));
```

No need at all for the other observable.

But if you really need to use it then the `Switch()` extension method is your best bet. Try this:

```
booleans
    .Select(b => b == true
        ? Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)) 
        : Observable.Empty<long>())
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(l => DoStuff(l));
```

It's pretty clean and helps to show that there are empty periods if the checkbox is not ticked.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I also need to do other stuff with the boolean observable, so I prefer to keep it as a stream.

Comment: @Boris - the first option doesn't prevent you from having a stream. Keep in mind that observables are like enumerables in that each time you subscribe to them you get a new subscription to the underlying source, not a shared subscription to the observable. Nevertheless the second option should them work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Just to note, the second option has a slightly different behaviour than my initial approach, and I don't like it as much, since the `Observable.Interval(...).Where(...)` still seems clearer to me. Your first option is by far the simplest approach of all the answers, and I like it, but for reasons explained in a response under the accepted answer, I still prefer the BehaviourSubject approach. Thanks again.